# Do I need a Japan transit visa?

Tags: indian-citizens, canada, japan

I am travelling from India to Canada and I have a stopover in Japan, where I will be changing airports. Landing in HND, flying from NRT.
I have an Indian passport and I'm a Canadian Permanent Resident.

I was told different scenarios by different people, so I'm not sure what to believe. My next steps are to call the embassy.

Do I need a transit visa?

Update: I cannot apply for eVisa as it is a travel visa and I need a transit visa, which has to be applied in person. I am waiting to see if Japan Airlines will offer me a shore Pass on the spot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not an immigration lawyer nor expert on Japanese nor Indian visa policies, but:

- India is *not* on [the list](https://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/short/novisa.html) of visa exempt countries.
- HND to NRT is anything but a sterile airside transfer, you very much need to enter the country and use the public transport system.

Ergo: looks to me like you very much need a visa.

The most applicable visa for your case would probably be a [tourism visa](https://www.mofa.go.jp/files/000121327.pdf), which has fairly benign requirements in your case:

- You need a proof of planned entry and departure flights, which is what this is all about anyway.
- You need to provide your intended itinerary, which is very straight forward.
- You need proof of sufficient funds to cover your expenses, which will be about ¥1,600 if you take the Keikyū line.

Your Canadian residency does entitle you to applying for an [eVisa](https://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/visaonline.html), which should simplify the process even more.

Comment: I think their Canadian residency should help in getting an e-visa for Japan, as described on https://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/index.html?

"All foreign nationals/people who reside in the following countries/region and are required to obtain a short-term visa on visiting Japan are eligible to apply for a visa online from March 27, 2023. Brazil, Cambodia, Canada, Mongolia, Saudi Arabia, Singapore, South Africa, Taiwan, United Arab Emirates, United Kingdom, U.S.A."

Comment: Thank you, what an oversight. Corrected the information.

Comment: Thanks all this was super helpful.